# Write a Regex which does NOT contain double letters anywhere (such as aa or bb,etc) Σ={a,b,c}

Tags: regular-language, automata

I am doing a theory of automata course at University and the teacher gave us this question.

Is this correct

```
[^[[[a-c]*aa[a-c]*]|[[a-c]*bb[a-c]*]|[[a-c]*cc[a-c]*]]]
```

Comment: "Write a Regex which does NOT contain double letters anywhere" --- your regex certainly contains double letters.

Comment: Zerkms the caret notation takes care of that,it means anything except aa,bb,cc

Comment: Re-read your own question: "Write a Regex which does NOT contain double letters anywhere". You either worded it poorly or do not entirely understand what regular expressions is.

Comment: Zerkms I am a student, my knowledge is very limited compared to you sir. My learning was the if you use the Caret notation it means one of two things in regular expression. On its own, it matches the start of the input. So     ^bar matches bar but not     foobar. Caret between square braces means "any character except". So [^abc] means "any character other than a, b, or c".

So in my RE which maybe wrong, I am using the caret notation to tell that any combination of A,b,c using (a-c)* not including aa,bb,cc

I am open to your suggestion as well

Answer (score 2):

Wrong. `[^…]` only works on character level.

Regular expression does not have an operator that complements the whole language (Σ* − L).

---

Here is a mechanical construction. You should observe that "no `aa`/`bb`/`cc`" means an `a` can only be followed by `b`,`c` or `ε`, and similar for the other two letter. So you can start from the regular grammar in DFA form:

> S → ε | a A | b B | c C
>   A → ε | b B | c C
>   B ­→ ε | c C | a A
>   C ­→ ε | a A | b B

and then [convert the DFA to regular expression](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions) by eliminating each state one by one:

> S → ε | a (ε | b B | c C) | b B | c C
>  B → ε | c C | a (ε | b B | c C)
>  C → ε | b B | a (ε | b B | c C)
>
>  Expanding,
>
>  S → ε | b B | c C | a | ab B | ac C
>  B → ε | c C | a | ab B | ac C
>  C → ε | b B | a | ab B | ac C

You could do some simplification meanwhile, e.g. change all right-recursion `X → y | z X` to the Kleene star `X → z* y`, or merge common branches `X → xy | y` with optionals `X → x? y`.

> S → a? | a? b B | a? c C
>  B → (ab)* a? | (ab)* a? c C
>  C → (ac)* a? | (ac)* a? b B

You should be able to figure out the rest.

(Note that there can be multiple regular expressions describing the same language. While this method can produce a solution, it may not be shortest one.)

Comment: I would say "regular grammar" instead of "DFA grammar" because a DFA is an automaton, not a grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z])\1).*$
```

This regex used a negative lookahead which asserts that the same two characters never occur back-to-back anywhere in the string.  The quantity `([A-Za-z])` matches *and* captures every single letter in the string, and then `\1` uses that captured letter.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Hey Tim, our teacher wants this without the use of (?,$,etc , I am not even sure if he will accept caret notation. 

Also is (a+b+c)* the same as (a-c)* ?

Comment: If you don't use a lookahead, you'll have to use an alternation.  This probably will mean an ugly regex with 26 terms.  Are you sure that you understand the requirements?

Comment: Tim as you see in the question the sigma is A,B,C only, so three letters are in use only

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP is asking about regular expression in the formal language sense, not the more powerful "regex" that we programmers use :).

Comment: Yes Kennytm because the course is theory of autuomata, the regex comes in our next course called compiler construction

Answer (score 0):

N.B.: this is a more didactic answer trying to get the student thinking, it does not contain the solution to the actual problem.

I assume that you only have to worry about 3 letters as per your question, not about all 26+ ones.

Note that, without spoiling anything, the purpose of the exercise is very likely to show the practical and theoretical limits of regular expression when trying to track contextual information.

You also seem to be restricted to the bare language without more recent constructs like lookaheads.

They regexp you came up with does not compute, regarding the "canonical" regexp features.  E.g., you have nested square brackets. Without more specification, basic regexp have (), |, [], ., *, +, ? with only the () nesting. Note that in the strict theoretical version, there may be even less meta symbols allowed.  Trust your notes/textbook on that as we do not know what your teacher will accept.

Try to come up with a solution, and then you only need to find a single counter example. Then try to work around that example until you cannot think of any more...

One more hint: Try to work from what you are given.  Can you make an expression for `a...a` where `...` contains no `a` but still follows the rule of no `bb` nor `cc`?

Comment: AnoE Yes you are exactly right, help me out with it

Comment: @fahdriazali, I cannot help you more. If I give you the solution, this will hurt you more than it will help.  I suggest you study the available symbols and the inner workings of your automaton again. Try to think like the machine...If you come up with another solution I will be happy to verify it.

Comment: AnoE You must be a professor...jk , 

here are some state diagrams http://imgur.com/a/omDEH
and from that 

     ((a|ba) ((ba)*|c(bc)*a)*)
| ((c|bc) ((bc)*|a(ba)*c)*)

Comment: @fahdriazali, no, I am not a professor.  That other answer by kennytm is good, although it spoils you too much, for my taste. If you are a CS student,  I would really suggest that you try to get a more indepth understanding of the topic though, unless this is just a mandatory "filler" course for you...

Comment: Hey AnoE, I have to submit this to class in exactly 12 hours for some extra credit marks. Maybe you can help me out this time?

Comment: This page contains the solution, look around. @fahdriazali

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to construct a DFA for this language:

```
Q    e   Q'     Initial state: qI
qI   a   qA     Accepting states: qI, qA, qB, qC
qI   b   qB     Dead states: qD
qI   c   qC
qA   a   qD
qA   b   qB
qA   c   qC
qB   a   qA
qB   b   qD
qB   c   qC
qC   a   qA
qC   b   qC
qC   c   qD
qD   a   qD
qD   b   qD
qD   c   qD
```

With a DFA in hand, you can use any well-known algorithm for transforming a DFA into a regular expression to get an answer. These algorithms are known and running through them - automatically or by hand - will always give you a correct answer. Here is a question with answers showing how to go through this process: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2016/69